# Why would a relay only work sometimes?

Tags: relay

[image]It's in bridge saw cutting machine's electrical control panel. This relay is used for the upward movement of the hydraulic table of the machine.

When I connect it in the opposite direction it works, which means I have to switch it down to make the table come up.

I have changed the relay also, but it's not working. Sometimes it does work.

How can I solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: are you sure it is the relay that is broken?

Comment: What interlocks are in place to only allow the table to move safely? Check them.

Comment: Well I tried to help but I'm kind of getting the "talking to a wall" feeling here. It's not hard to trouble shoot this with a multimeter and some very basic understanding of relays and valves. Voting to close as repair question failing to "demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired" now. Hire someone who knows electronics to fix this for you.

Comment: I have checked with the multimeter. supply to relay is ok

Comment: one time a electrician came and he checked and he cannot find the problem

Answer (score 1):

"When I connect it in the opposite direction it works" In can be that one of the contacts has welded or oxidated, but not the other. On normal relays with multiple contacts, the contacts don't necessarily follow each other, but move individually (as opposed to safety relays).

> I have changed the relay also, but it's not working.

Then the problem isn't in the relay. I'd suspect cables and connectors. Use a multimeter to ensure there's a connection all the way to the valve.

If you have two on/off valves for moving the saw in either direction, the problem could of course also be related to the valves/hydraulics. To narrow down the problem, the easiest thing to do before anything else is to swap the two valve connectors and see if the problem remains on the same direction (the problem must be with the electronics/connections) or if the problem moves to the other valve (the problem is with the valve/hydraulics).

Also another very basic thing to check when troubleshooting is: does the relay  activate at all? You should hear the click and in case of transparent relays you can also see it. If the relay doesn't activate then the problem would be on the coil side or in your control panel.

---

EDIT after pictures

Well... your connector is covered in possibly conductive dirt. This could both cause shorts or failures to contact. It might also be oxidated. That one needs to be placed into something that's actually IP65 proof. It might be possible to salvage it by cleaning it up, but otherwise any connector with about the same current rating would do the trick. Looks like you could replace it with simple DIN rail terminal blocks or a Harting industrial connector. If placing it in a box outdoors then go with gold plated terminals to minimize problems with oxidation.

Comment: what did you mean by coil side?

Comment: @RichuKuruvilla The relay coil. Your control panel + relay coil driving will be on the "primary" side and the valves on the "secondary" side of the relay.

Comment: sir, this is the electrical panel

Comment: no the relay not active

Comment: I also changed the relay

Comment: @RichuKuruvilla Yes you said that already. If you can confirm that the relay doesn't activate (you have transparent ones so you will be able to see if it does), then measure if you have voltage supply on the coil side of the relay when you activate the corresponding button etc on the control panel. If not, test for connection to whatever is driving the coil. It's not clear if it's driven directly through a button/switch or if there's a PLC sitting in between.

Comment: it can be controlled by the plc and also there is a direct switch for the up and down movement , we can control the table form from the system and from the switch

Comment: I have tried cleaning the connector but it don't work

Comment: in that same control switch if we press down the the table we be down and motor will be runing

Comment: only  when we press upward it is not working and if I change the connection in the opposite way and press the down button the table will be up

Comment: Sounds like it is the button itself then.